# How to improve autoloading of Magit's git-commit-mode and other minor modes

Tags: magit, start-up

#### Aim

I would like to arrange for Magit's minor mode `git-commit-mode` to be enabled whenever a relevant Git file (e.g. `COMMIT_EDITMSG`) is visited, from both within Emacs (e.g. `magit-commit`) and without (e.g. `git commit` with environment variables `EDITOR` set to `emacsclient --create-frame --no-wait` and `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` empty).

I would, however, like the loading of `git-commit.el` to be deferred until such a file is visited, as loading it and its dependencies increases my Emacs startup time by nearly 100% (i.e. an extra `~0.7s`).

#### Background

I have seen major modes usually tackle this problem by autoloading an addition to `auto-mode-alist`. The single autoloaded entry-point that `git-commit.el` defines, on the other hand, is the globalised minor mode itself, which modifies `find-file-hook` instead. This means that there is no way (obvious to me) to enable the mode or read the value of `git-commit-filename-regexp` without loading the package, its baggage and the kitchen sink.

What I have successfully done until now is add the equivalent of `(cons git-commit-filename-regexp #'git-commit-mode)` to `auto-mode-alist` (despite its being a minor mode), where I manually substitute the value of the `defconst` `git-commit-filename-regexp` as defined in the package.

#### Questions

1. What effects does adding a minor mode entry to `auto-mode-alist` have compared to adding a major mode? Does it create a (potentially trivial) risk of breaking something, somewhere? Does this only work with `git-commit-mode` by chance?
2. Is there a more elegant or idiomatic solution for autoloading `git-commit-mode` specifically and minor modes generally?
3. Could `git-commit.el` be extended in some way to alleviate this issue?

#### Update

Those interested, see [here](https://github.com/magit/magit/pull/3070) for the followup discussion and patch on the project's page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What effects does adding a minor mode entry to `auto-mode-alist` have compared to adding a major mode? Does it create a (potentially trivial) risk of breaking something, somewhere? Does this only work with `git-commit-mode` by chance?

You can really use *any* function in an `auto-mode-alist` entry. It needn't actually be a mode (although you might well want it to invoke one or more modes).

So you could even specify a function which calls both major and minor modes. Of course you could also define a derived mode of that major mode, and invoke the minor modes in the derived mode's body, which would seem cleaner.

```el
(define-derived-mode my-git-commit-mode text-mode "Git Commit"
  (git-commit-mode 1))
```

If you don't specify (or otherwise invoke) a major mode, then the buffer will remain in `fundamental-mode`.

Anyhow, it's `set-auto-mode-0` that ultimately handles the selected function, and it simply calls the function, whatever it is.

The potential side-effect is that if `set-visited-file-name` is invoked on the buffer then the specified function may be called again. Normally the function would only be called there if the detected mode differed from the current `major-mode`, but if the function in question is not a major mode then it will never match. If the function is a minor mode, then calling it again would tend to be fairly harmless (at least since Emacs 24; in earlier versions it would toggle the mode, which is more of a problem).

> Is there a more elegant or idiomatic solution for autoloading `git-commit-mode` specifically and minor modes generally?

You might alternatively use `find-file-hook` to test the filename and call the minor mode.

I don't think the `auto-mode-alist` approach is a bad one, though.

And again, if you're concerned about not using a major mode, then simply define one for the purpose.

> Could git-commit.el be extended in some way to alleviate this issue?

If it autoloaded the `git-commit-filename-regexp` variable definition, then you would have access to that (default) value without loading the library.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer and advice. What `git-commit.el` seems to do to avoid falling back to `fundamental-mode` is call `normal-mode` with `auto-mode-alist` `let`-bound to a mapping of the current `buffer-file-name` to `git-commit-major-mode`, a customisable variable which determines the user's preferred major mode. [Here](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/master/lisp/git-commit.el#L409-L414) is the relevant code, in case you are interested.

Comment: I think I will stick with the `auto-mode-alist` approach and send a patch adding an `autoload` cookie to the package maintainers.

Comment: Should we also add something like: `(setq git-commit-major-mode 'my-git-commit-mode)` ?

Comment: alper: Maybe, if `my-git-commit-mode` does something *additional* to calling `git-commit-mode`?  Otherwise there's probably no reason to do that (although you might still prefer to for the sake of consistency).